# Unable to run docker commands after new docker installation

Tags: bash, docker, macos-sierra

I am trying to get docker up and running on my macOS-sierra but i am facing some problems in doing so . Whenever i try to run **docker ps** command on my machine it throws up an error :-

```
bash: /Applications/Docker/Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh: No such file or directory
```

before this i was using docker toolbox but uninstalled it to install the new docker for mac software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quickstart Terminal was a helper that was configuring the terminal before Docker for Mac, but you dont need it anymore.
Previously Docker uses the default machine in Virtual Box, but Docker for Mac uses a more native virtualization.
If no DOCKER_HOST is set it will automatically use it, so you can simply use the normal terminal.

Comment: But still whenever i try to run any docker commands it gives me the same error.

Comment: Are you using the MacOS Terminal or the Quickstart Terminal, because this script should not be called. Or do you have an alias to automaticly call that script?

Comment: I was using an alias . Removing that worked for me. Thanks.